# Android Inconsistent activity start from service

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service, google-cloud-messaging

So basically I'm implementing GCM and upon receiving a notification (Not clicking on it), it should start an activity. This works sometimes while sometimes it doesn't. It seems to be completely random.

When it SOMETIMES doesn't work:

- When the application is in foreground
- When the application is in the homescreen (This makes it just open the application and not the intended activity);

GCMIntentService.java (This does get called all the way to startActivity):

```
            Intent call = new Intent(this, CallActivity.class);
            call.putExtra("name", name);
            call.putExtra("picture", picture);
            call.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
            call.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
            call.putExtra("request_id", requestId);
            call.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            call.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
            call.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED +
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD +
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON +
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
            startActivity(call);
```

However I noticed that the CallActivity DOES NOT start at all (In cases where it's not working and the application is in background). So it does not call onCreate or onResume.

If it does affect anything, the application is running in this mode:

> android:launchMode="singleTask"

This was because there were problems before where there were basically two different activities when you view all running applications.

CallActivity manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".CallActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where is pending intent?

Comment: @Raghunandan There isn't one because it's supposed to open the activity directly and not upon clicking of the notification

Comment: Looks like there was an issue on an [L build](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1902) where FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD and FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED don't work as intended when added together. You may want to check if this reproduces when you comment out that addFlags line.